# How to print series 1.5, 2.3, 3.1, 3.9, 4.7 in php

Tags: php, series

This is the code I've written but am not getting how to write for alternative addition and subtraction

```
<?php
$start=1.5;
$inc=0.8;
echo "$start, ";
$n=4;
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
{
    $start=$start+$inc;
    if($i==$n){
        echo "$start";
    }else{
        echo "$start, ";
    }
    $inc+=0.8;
}
?>
```

output for above code is 1.5,2.3,3.9,6.3,9.5
What are changes needed

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You're incrementing `$inc` each time. That means first you're going to add .8, then 1.6, then 2.4...

Answer (score 1):

Or simply make [`range`](https://www.php.net/range) do all the work:

```
foreach (range(1.5, 10, 0.8) as $item) {
    echo $item . PHP_EOL;
}

// or
echo implode(', ', range(1.5, 10, 0.8));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to loop until the value of `$n`, you can do this way. Not sure about this part **"but am not getting how to write for alternative addition and subtraction"**

```
<?php
$start=1.5;
$inc=0.8;
echo "start=$start".PHP_EOL;
$n=4;
for($i=$start;$i<=$n;$i=$i+$inc)
{
 $result[] = $i;
}
echo implode(',',$result);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/tkPbI

Answer (score 0):

Make the for loop do all the work

```
$start=1.5;
$inc=0.8;
$stop=4.7;
$out = '';    

for($i=$start; $i<=$stop; $i+=$inc)
{
    $out .= $i . ',';    
}
$out = trim($out, ',');
echo $out;
```

RESULT

```
1.5,2.3,3.1,3.9,4.7
```